# MySQL SHOW COLUMNS

Tags: mysql

Teria como trazer somente as colunas do banco e ordenar da formar que eu quero por exemplo:

```
show columns FROM table
```

O código acima traz todas as colunas da tabela.

trazer as colunas ordenadas.

```
SHOW TABLE.COLUNA1,
     TABLE.COLUNA2
FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tenta usar [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-schema.html):

```
SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='yourdatabasename' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='yourtablename';
```